# Scala create xhtml elements dynamically

Tags: scala, dictionary, loops, indexing

Given a String list

```
val www = List("http://bloomberg.com", "http://marketwatch.com");
```

I want to dynamically generate

```
<span id="span1">http://bloomberg.com</span>
<span id="span2">http://marketwatch.com</span>

def genSpan(web: String) = <span id="span1"> + web + </span>;

www.map(genSpan); // How can I pass the loop index?
```

How can I use the Scala map function to generate the ids (span1, span2), as 1 and 2 are the loop indexes?
Or is the only way is to use for comprehension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `zipWithIndex` which turns a list into a list of tuples `(value,index)`.  In your case,

```
def genSpan(web: String, id: Int) = {
  <span id={ "span%d".format(id) }> { web } </span>
}
www.zipWithIndex.map(x => genSpan(x._1,x._2+1))
```

Note that the index, `x._2`, starts from zero but you want to start from one, so I added one in the call to `genSpan`.  Note also that you can set attributes using Scala code by wrapping the Scala code in `{}`.

Comment: need to wrap "web" as well,
<span id={ "span%d".format(id) }> + {web} + </span>

Thanks!

Comment: @portoalet - Yes, whoops!  Fixed now.  (No `+` by the way--everything inside the XML block is output.)